# Gitlab CI: Replace only: *allowed_branches with rules:

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Looking at how to replace gitlabs 'only' syntax with 'rules' syntax for a particular case.

I have the following snippet as an example:

```
myjob:
  <<: *anchor_code
  only: *my_branches
```

where my_branches is

```
.my_branches: &my_branches
  - master
  - release
  - /^hotfix\/.+$/
```

I would like to replace "only" from the job above with gitlabs "rules" syntax.  How would I accomplish that with rules?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```yml
myjob:
  <<: *anchor_code
  only: *my_branches
  rules:
    - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "release"'
    - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /^hotfix\/.+$/'
```

Unfortunately I don't think we will be able to anchor the branches like you have in your original yml.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I had going as well and so it confirms my understanding.  Appreciate you time.

Comment: you can't combine only with rules

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine `only:` and `rules:` in one job, and YAML anchors (nor `extends:`) also do not seem to work there.

```
myjob:
  <<: *anchor_code
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "release"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "/^hotfix\/.+$/"'
```